# What's the best way to store currency symbols in postgresql ?

Tags: postgresql

I need to create currency symbol column and tried to save it as bytea with unicode value , but I see it in the database manager (intellij) as raw code and not the actual symbol character.
What's the best and acceptable way to do it ?

Comment: why not just text?..

Comment: because the Euro sign (for example) is not in the ascii table, and if you just insert it as String , it won't be displayed properly once you retrieve it.

Comment: ascii table?.. `show server_encoding` ?..

Comment: Didn't get you. Do you have a working suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

I must miss the whole point, cos I would just:

```
x=# with utf(sign,currency) as (values(e'\u20BD','Rubble'),(e'\u20AC','Euro'),(e'\u20AF','Drachma'))
select *,pg_typeof(sign) from utf;
 sign | currency | pg_typeof
------+----------+-----------
 ₽    | Rubble   | text
 €    | Euro     | text
 ₯    | Drachma  | text
(3 rows)
```

UTF codes taken from https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_currency.asp

also wanted at first to use postgres internal monetary type, because it puts sign to a right place (before or after the amount), but failed at Hindi locale:

```
x=# set lc_monetary TO 'hi_IN';
ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "hi_IN"
Time: 0.332 ms
x=# set lc_monetary TO 'EN_ie';
SET
Time: 0.514 ms
x=# select 1::money;
 money
-------
 €1.00
(1 row)

Time: 3.313 ms
x=# set lc_monetary TO 'RU_ru';
SET
Time: 10.178 ms
x=# select 1::money;
   money
-----------
 1,00 руб.
(1 row)
```